# MSI laptop CPU reaching high temperature

Tags: cpu, windows-installer, overheating

I recently bought a MSI GF65 Thin. The CPU reaches around 4.5GHz for simple tasks like searching a string on a file using grep command (dual booted with ubuntu-20.04) and the CPU temp reaches around 92 degrees.
CPU config:

```
Model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz Stepping: 2 CPU MHz: 2600.000 CPU max MHz: 5000.0000 CPU min MHz: 800.0000
CPU freq while running the tasks:
Every 2.0s: grep 'cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo

cpu MHz : 4254.384 cpu MHz : 4577.275 cpu MHz : 2600.000 cpu MHz : 2600.000
cpu MHz : 4576.879 cpu MHz : 2600.000 cpu MHz : 2600.000 cpu MHz : 2600.000
cpu MHz : 2600.000 cpu MHz : 2600.000 cpu MHz : 2600.000 cpu MHz : 4370.464
```

Is this normal for an i7 CPU to reach 4.5Ghz and 92 degrees (I am also using a cooling pad) for such tasks? Could it be because of MSI Dragon Center?

Comment: 92 C is high indeed but not alarmingly high.

Comment: If you are concerned about the integrity of your laptop, you should ask MSI since it's still under warranty. They should give you precise advice about how your laptop is behaving

Comment: Your processor is not overheating and properly boosting to the appropriate frequency and returning to it’a base frequency.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted in comments: these temperatures are within the normal range for your CPU and indicate the system is likely functioning OK.